# Descartes’ Clear and Distinct Principle

Tags: descartes

Can someone explain Descartes’ clear and distinct principle in depth? I am reading his *Meditations*, and find the explanation presented there to be short and inadequate for such a bold claim. I would also appreciate if someone could present counter-arguments for this principle as well.

Comment: By asking this question it's clear that you couldn't form clear and distinct principles from reading Descartes' *Meditations*, but on the other hand, as mundanely known linguistically, clear and distinct principles are contrasted with or opposed to those unclear or confused principles, ergo you've already formed a clear and distinct principle as your personal private criterion to tell them apart to satisfy your hoped or anticipated fitting answer...

Comment: See [Descartes’ Method](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-method/) and [D's Epistemology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/#CaDRuleRoadPerfKnow)

Comment: You should make the question more specific unless you want long-winded commentary that can be found in encyclopedias. Here is the outline of his argument, [SEP, C&D Rule](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/#CaDRuleRoadPerfKnow). The main objection goes back to Arnauld and is known as the [Cartesian circle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/#PerfKnowCircTrut). An even more obvious objection is that he weaves the world out of them, but, in hindsight at least, some of his "clear and distinct ideas" are clearly and distinctly wrong.

Comment: [*Meditations*, III](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Meditations_on_First_Philosophy/Meditation_III): "all the images of corporeal things [...] I will consider them as empty and false; and thus, holding converse only with myself, and closely examining my nature, I will endeavor to obtain by degrees a more intimate and familiar knowledge of myself. I am a thinking (conscious) thing, that is, a being who doubts, affirms, denies, knows a few objects, and is ignorant of many, although the things which I perceive or imagine are perhaps nothing at all apart from me [and in themselves],..." 1/2

Comment: 2/2 "... I am nevertheless assured that those modes of consciousness which I call perceptions and imaginations, in as far only as they are modes of consciousness, exist in me." **First step**: the information I receive from the senses are not reliable but my own existence as a "thinking thing" is certain.

Comment: "I have summed up all that I really know, or at least all that up to this time I was aware I knew. Now, as I am endeavoring to extend my knowledge more widely, I will consider with care whether I can still discover in myself anything further which I have not yet hitherto observed. I am certain that I am a thinking thing; but do I not therefore likewise know what is required to render me certain of a truth ? In this first knowledge, doubtless, there is nothing that gives me assurance of its truth except the clear and distinct perception of what I affirm." 1/2

Comment: 2/2 **Second setp**: why the knowledge that I've obtained above: I'm a thinking thing, is certain? Because it has a peculiar characteristic: I've a *clear and distinct* understanding of it and thus, "being clear and distinct" is the mark of true knowledge.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.